# Appropriate preposition in "your preference of/for time and venue"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, of-for

What is the most appropriate preposition for the following sentence?

> I would like to talk to you. Please let me know your preference **of/for** time and venue where we can meet.

I would also be happy to get a better construct for the idea I am trying to communicate.  Even [this](http://en.allexperts.com/q/General-Writing-Grammar-680/preference.htm) does not seem to give me any idea.

Comment: How to rewrite a text is not really [on topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq) here.

Comment: Can't we ask for grammatical correctness including a *better* and *more* appropriate way of saying something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have preferences *for* things more often than preferences *of* them, but *of* isn't incorrect here, nor the only alternative: *as to*, *regarding*, *in regards to*, and the like would also work. Rather than asking for a *preference for*, why not ask what the addressee *prefers*?

> I would like to meet with you. Is there a time or place you prefer?
>
> I would like to meet with you. Do you prefer a particular time or place?

Answer (score 3):

What a native speaker might say is *I think it would be very helpful if we could meet and talk about it. Do you have any preference for time and place?*

Comment: The phrase "for time and place" is clumsy and stilted, and is not likely to be used in common speech by native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers use the word *prefer/preference*.

A native speaker is more likely not to use that at all, but rather to ask directly, at least in conversation:

> I'd like to talk. When would be convenient?"

It might be a little less forthright in writing:

> It would help if we met to discuss this. When might we do that?

*Where* is omitted, because making an appointment is useless without a location, so it's customarily included in the answer — for example, "I'll be at home on Wednesday evening. How about then?" or "I can't do anything till Thursday. Come to the office at 3pm."

Answer (score 0):

The writing skill of a literate person definitely beats that of an average native.

That being said,

> "I would like to talk to you personally, please let me know when you have the time."

This sentence implies that such meeting will take place at the guest's convenience.